# Gitlab CI node module command

Tags: batch-file, npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a CI configuration which runs on a Windows machine. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file look like:

```
stages:
  - package

package:
  stage: package

  tags:
    - xxx-installer

  only:
    - master

  script:
    - Package.cmd

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - Extensions/
```

The script `Package.cmd` looks like:

```
@echo off    
echo -------------------------
echo Packaging Extension
echo -------------------------

call npm install web-ext --global

call web-ext build -s "App/" -a "Extensions/" -o true
```

The module `web-ext` is installed successfully, but while executing the `web-ext` command, I get the following error in my pipeline logs:

> 'web-ext' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However, if I execute the `Package.cmd` from the terminal on the same machine, it works completely fine.

So, is there anything that needs to be done so that the CI runner recognizes the node module command?

**Update:**
As per the suggestion by @SteveFest, I checked the `%path%` variable locations and I found `C:\Users\prerak\AppData\Roaming\npm` in it. However, when the CI script it executed, it prints the following output after installing the npm package:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\web-ext -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\bin\web-ext
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- web-ext@2.0.0 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
'web-ext' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I suppose, as the CI scriptis not running in my user session, it is installing the module at `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm` or at `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\bin\web-ext` location. So I added both these path in my `PATH` variable, but still the result is the same.

If incase, it's relevant, this is a Firefox web-extension project and I am trying to package the extension.

Comment: I don't think you need to `call command`. `command` alone will work fine. `call` should be(*not must be*) used to a label or another batch script.

Comment: @SteveFest If I do that, the script terminates after `npm install`. It does not go to the next command.

Comment: Does it show any errors?

Comment: @SteveFest Nope.

Comment: That is absolutely weird. Anyways, back to your question. Did the `npm install` command really install the `web-ext` into current folder or any folders in the `%path%` variable?

Comment: @SteveFest The CI script does not run in my user session, so I suppose it is installing the module at some other location. See the updated question with some details regarding it.